# How To Initiate Multiple Properties In Livewire On mount() Method

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-livewire

Does anyone know how to initiate these properties to "Data is not set yet." simultaneously without initiating each of them in an array?

```
    class HomeroomClass extends Component
    {
        public $homeroomClassName;
        public $homeroomClassSemester;
        public $homeroomClassStudent;
    
        public function mount()
        {
            if (auth()->user()->student->homeroomclass_id != NULL)
            {
                $this->homeroomClassName = Auth::user()->student->homeroomclass->name;
                $this->homeroomClassSemester = Auth::user()->student->homeroomclass->semester;
                $this->homeroomClassStudent = Student::query()->where('homeroom_class_id', auth()->user()->student->homeroomclass->id)->count();
            } 
            else
            {
                $this->fill(['homeroomClassName' => 'Data is not set yet.', 'homeroomClassSemester' => 'Data is not set yet.', 'homeroomClassStudent' => 'Data is not set yet.']);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not make it the default?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by default?

Comment: `public $homeroomClassName = 'Data is not set yet.'`

Comment: I've done that before and it's not tidy for my dev team. I'm intended to make my code cleaner and simpler. Do you have another way instead of initiating it one by one?

Comment: II don't understand how it's not tidy. You'll have to keep doing it one by one then.